# Export shapefile using pgsql2shp module in Python IDE

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I want to export the shapefile from a PostgreSQL database using python but i am getting an error of "column not exist". The value "Deurali" exists in table.

error shows:
[my code with error is shown in screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waHjS.png)
[image]

Comment: The may exist, but you're using `"Deruali"` (double quotes) instead of `'Deruali'`. Use the latter.

Comment: Still of no work